# BeautifulSoup not returning the parsed html text from a paragraph tag

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Thank you for looking over my concern, I am a beginner with python web scraping with bs4, and the code that I wrote using beautifulsoup is not returning the required paragraph.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


def downloadUrl(link):
    req = requests.get(link)
    statusCode = req.status_code
    if(statusCode==200):
        return req.text
    else:
        return  ('Did not connect :( status code {}'.format(statusCode))

def ParseText(html):
    soupParser = bs(html,features="html.parser")
    table =  soupParser.select('div[class="_3xX726aBn29LDbsDtzr_6E._1Ap4F5maDtT1E1YuCiaO0r.D3IL3FD0RFy_mkKLPwL4"]')
    txt = ''
    for x in table:
        txt+=(x.find('p').text)
    return txt
        

link = input('Enter url')
print(ParseText(downloadUrl(link)))
```

the link I used is from Reddit [Reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/af6vy7/how_do_i_make_programming_interesting_for_children/). The Paragraph I want it to return is this one.

```
                 How do I make programming interesting for children?
I'm 15 and I'm doing some volunteering work teaching programming to children (9-11 yrs). For the first few weeks we did some things with Scratch so they have at the very least a basic understanding of computing. 
In my most recent lesson I introduced them to Python. We started off with the most basic but perhaps one of the most important programs "Hello, World!". 
I offered an explanation for each part of the program like what print does, the content of the brackets, why we are using quotation marks etc. 
I made sure to make it as simple as possible but the majority of the children didn't understand and I've noticed that when they don't understand they like to go off and do something else completely unrelated to the course. 
Then I went onto input and that made it even more confusing.
 My friend who is helping me was pretty adamant on not offering any explanation whatsoever because he thinks they wont understand but I really do want them getting engaged with programming. 
There are around three people in my class who I believe have a genuine talent and interest in programming so I want to be able to generate that same interest amongst the others. 
I try explaining why we need programming and I thought the idea of developing games and websites would interest them but that was futile. 
Is there any way to make this more interesting for children or is does it just come naturally? Maybe I could have some learning resources 
that make programming more enjoyable but also good for learning, like challenges or larger projects? Any help would be appreciated because I want them to have the same interest in programming that I do.
```

Answer (score 1):

The "new" version of Reddit is using JavaScript to render the page (so some elements are invisible to BeautifulSoup) - you can use `selenium` to parse the data. Other options are using the Reddit API do download the information, or using "old" version of Reddit:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Add "old" instead of "www" to URL:
url = 'https://old.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/af6vy7/how_do_i_make_programming_interesting_for_children/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.select_one('a.title').text
text = soup.select_one('#siteTable .usertext-body').text

print(title)
print(text)
```

Prints:

```
How do I make programming interesting for children?
I'm 15 and I'm doing some volunteering work teaching programming to children (9-11 yrs). For the first few weeks we did some things with Scratch so they have at the very least a basic understanding of computing. In my most recent lesson I introduced them to Python. We started off with the most basic but perhaps one of the most important programs "Hello, World!". I offered an explanation for each part of the program like what print does, the content of the brackets, why we are using quotation marks etc. I made sure to make it as simple as possible but the majority of the children didn't understand and I've noticed that when they don't understand they like to go off and do something else completely unrelated to the course. Then I went onto input and that made it even more confusing. My friend who is helping me was pretty adamant on not offering any explanation whatsoever because he thinks they wont understand but I really do want them getting engaged with programming. There are around three people in my class who I believe have a genuine talent and interest in programming so I want to be able to generate that same interest amongst the others. I try explaining why we need programming and I thought the idea of developing games and websites would interest them but that was futile. Is there any way to make this more interesting for children or is does it just come naturally? Maybe I could have some learning resources that make programming more enjoyable but also good for learning, like challenges or larger projects? Any help would be appreciated because I want them to have the same interest in programming that I do.
```

---

If you want to wrap the text, you can use `textwrap` builtin module:

```
from textwrap import wrap
print('\n'.join(wrap(text)))
```

Prints:

```
I'm 15 and I'm doing some volunteering work teaching programming to
children (9-11 yrs). For the first few weeks we did some things with
Scratch so they have at the very least a basic understanding of
computing. In my most recent lesson I introduced them to Python. We
started off with the most basic but perhaps one of the most important
programs "Hello, World!". I offered an explanation for each part of
the program like what print does, the content of the brackets, why we
are using quotation marks etc. I made sure to make it as simple as
possible but the majority of the children didn't understand and I've
noticed that when they don't understand they like to go off and do
something else completely unrelated to the course. Then I went onto
input and that made it even more confusing. My friend who is helping
me was pretty adamant on not offering any explanation whatsoever
because he thinks they wont understand but I really do want them
getting engaged with programming. There are around three people in my
class who I believe have a genuine talent and interest in programming
so I want to be able to generate that same interest amongst the
others. I try explaining why we need programming and I thought the
idea of developing games and websites would interest them but that was
futile. Is there any way to make this more interesting for children or
is does it just come naturally? Maybe I could have some learning
resources that make programming more enjoyable but also good for
learning, like challenges or larger projects? Any help would be
appreciated because I want them to have the same interest in
programming that I do.
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej I made the changes using old version of URL but now I am getting some errors ,

Comment: ```def ParseText(link):
      soupParser = bs(requests.get(link).content,'html.parser')
      title = soupParser.select_one('a.title').text 
      return soupParser.select_one('#siteTable .usertext-body').text 

        

link = input('Enter url')
print(ParseText(link))

```

Comment: did not give the dictionary of headers though, but I suppose it is optional isn't it?

Comment: @PawanNirpal The reddit needs that you supply the `User-Agent` HTTP header. Put `headers=` parameter to `requests.get()`

Comment: How do I get that header parameter value?

Comment: @PawanNirpal You can use for example `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}` or other User-Agent. You may look at Firefox/Chrome developer tools -> Network tab at the requests headers your browser is doing.

Comment: Andrej I did something else instead and I didn't get Reddit but I scrapped a travel blog by this

Comment: ```def ParseText(link):
    soupParser = bs(requests.get(link,headers = requests.get()).content,'html.parser')
    title = soupParser.select_one('a.title').text 
    return soupParser.select_one('#siteTable .usertext-body').text 
    

link = input('Enter url')
print(ParseText(link))```

Comment: @PawanNirpal It shoud be `soupParser = bs(requests.get(link,headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'}).content,'html.parser')`

Comment: Oh Yes I do understand but I'm not getting the header dict in dev-tools of chrome so I did the above thing with justext It seems to be giving me results for some sites, but not for Reddit